# Install printer driver from "tar.gz" file

Tags: drivers, printing, installation

I have Samsung ML-1915 printer, the printer wizard which pop ups when I connected the printer couldn't find the driver.

So I download the driver from Samsung website, and now i unzip the tar.gz and got this files

[image]

What I need to do next???

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at the `Installer.htm` file. Just drag it into Firefox/Chrome and see what it says. That should contain some sort of instruction, but as a guess, I'd say you'd want to open a terminal, CD to this directory and then run `sudo sh install.sh`.

The Arch Linux wiki [has some instructions](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=97460) that differ slightly from this, essentially just using the PPD from the unified driver.